# What is a shop of shoes called in the UK?

Tags: british-english

What is a shop of shoes called in the UK?

Is it called:

**shoe shop**

or

**shoes shop**

or

**shoe store**

or

**shoes store**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**shoe [shop](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shop)** is the correct term in the UK, and **shoe [store](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/store)** is the correct term in the US.

Both are noun-type things made up of two words- these are called [compound nouns](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/styleguide/chapter/compound-nouns/).

You don't generally use hyphens in compound nouns unless it contains prefixes, suffixes, prepositions, conjunctions, determiners, etc, for example minimum-wage, rent-a-cop or oven-to-table-ware.

You generally only make the **final** word in a compound noun plural. So, even though there are many shoes in the shop, you do not make **shoe** plural.

Answer (score 7):

A shop that sells shoes is called a **[shoe shop](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/shoe-shop)** in the UK.